# apt help text and messages in wrong language

Tags: apt, language-support, locale

I am having a system with mixed locale. Text languages are set to English, number formatting, currencies etc are set to German. This works very well with the only exception of apt. All messages and help texts of the apt commands (apt-get, apt-cache, etc.) are always in German:

e.g.:

```
apt-get --help                                                                                                                                                                                               
apt 1.6.12ubuntu0.1 (amd64)
Aufruf: apt-get [Optionen] befehl
        apt-get [Optionen] install|remove paket1 [paket2 ...]
        apt-get [Optionen] source paket1 [paket2 ...]

apt-get ist ein Befehlszeilenwerkzeug zum Herunterladen von Paketen (und
Informationen zu diesen Paketen) von authentifizierten Paketquellen sowie
für deren Installation, Aktualisierung und Entfernung zusammen mit ihren
Paketabhängigkeiten.
...
```

This is behavior is the same for my personal user account and for the root user.

The locale settings for my user account are like:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:de
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

LC_ALL is not set, but even if I set this env var explicitely

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

The language of apt output does not change.

Which locale variable actually affects apt commands? How can I convince apt talking English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:de
```

That does not do what you think it does. Since the original language is en_US, there are basically no en_US translations, so for applications which understand the `LANGUAGE` environment variable, gettext picks German translations instead.

Change that to:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

P.S. You ought to have the issue for many more applications than APT.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar, your answer pointed me into the right direction. I am using KDE and had set two languages in the System Settings > Reguinal Settings Language :  "American English" and "German". The according config file is:  `~/.config/plasma-localerc`. Removing "German" from the settings dialog removes the LANGUAGE entry from that config file. After re-login the command translations are all in English.